# statsmodels missing .api, .regression, etc

Tags: python, installation, statsmodels

I am trying to call `statsmodels.api` and `statsmodels.regression` in python 3.5 in a jupyter notebook.  This is inside a virtual env.  Using OSX El Capitan.  I get the error

```
AttributeError: module 'statsmodels' has no attribute 'regression'
```

and similarly for calling `statsmodels.api`:

```
AttributeError: module 'statsmodels' has no attribute 'api'
```

Tried uninstalling and reinstalling via `pip` to no avail.  Checked the `statsmodels` folder in `site-packages`, and it seems complete.  This is for the latest version `statsmodels 0.8.0`.  I also tried it for a separate python 2.7 venv, and am running into the same issue.  Any clues as to what's going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out to be an import mistake.  According to [statsmodels doc](http://www.statsmodels.org/stable/importpaths.html), the recommended import is `import statsmodels.api as sm`.  I was using the import line `import statsmodels as sm`, which couldn't directly access the `.api` module.